# Flask redirect command intermittently redirecting to http instead of https links

Tags: docker, flask, redirect, apache2, traefik

I'm using flask running on an apache2 docker container behind Traefik. The app is a simple guest book app. It has a feature that allows you to vote on entries so they gain points. This link just updates the database and then returns them to the homepage. For some reason, intermittently, it will try to redirect to an http link of the homepage instead of an https link. This is handled by Traefik which redirects back to the https link. However, I'd like to figure out why it's happening.

So far I've tried just adding a "check" link to the homepage and clicking that to eliminate the vote code as an issue, all it does is redirect back to the homepage and the issue still happens intermittently. Interestingly sometimes I actually get a 200 status using this link which I don't think should happen on a redirect.

Here's what the setup looks like:

## **init**.py

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def homepage():
    form = GuestbookForm(request.form)
    
    if "ID" not in session:
        session["ID"] = genuserid();
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            name = form.name.data
            message = form.message.data
            setData( {"name":name, "message":message} )
            
    
    d = getData()
    if d[0] == 0:
        return render_template("guestbook.html", form=form, d=d[1])
    else:
        return str(d[1])

@app.route('/check/')
def check():
    return redirect(url_for("homepage"))
```

### Relevant section of docker-compose.yml for traefik

```
traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      #Setups auto ssl with letsencrypt using http challenge.
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=jcusitar@gmail.com"
      #Stores the certs in a json file that persists.
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--serverstransport.insecureskipverify=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"

guestbook:
    image: guestbook:dev
    labels:
      # Enable container for traefik routing
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.guestbook-redirect-web-secure.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.guestbook-web.middlewares=guestbook-redirect-web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.guestbook-web.rule=Host(`domain`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.guestbook-web.entrypoints=web"
      
      - "traefik.http.routers.guestbook-web-secure.rule=Host(`domain`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.guestbook-web-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.guestbook-web-secure.tls.certresolver=myresolver" 
      - "traefik.http.services.guestbook.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
    volumes:
      - "./guestbookwww:/var/www/"
    networks:
      - stack
```

Please let me know what you think might be going on. If there's any other info needed, I can add it.

### EDIT:

I discovered it seems to be something to do with the redirect function. I redirect to the entire url (ie: https://sub.domain.ca) and that works fine. Redirecting to "/" produces this behavior.